# Is there an R function to create a data frame of the logarithmic equations?

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

First, is there a way to fix my code to include ln(x) in the equation. For example, the plot in the equation is shown as y=1.2 + 0.32x, but instead should be y=1.2 +0.32ln(x).

Lastly, I'm trying to figure out is there a way to create either a new data frame that would allow me to summarize all the plots logarithmic equations that resulted from using stat_regline_equation(formula=y~log(x)).

[image]

```
iris<-rotated.plot.data %>% 
select(`2014-02-03 06:10:00` : `2014-09-30 22:10:00`)
plots <- purrr::map(iris, function(y) {
  ggplot(rotated.plot.data,
      aes(x=instrument.supersaturation, y={{ y }})) + 
    geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula = y~log(x)) + 
    stat_regline_equation(formula=y~log(x)) + 
     ylab("Nccn/Ncn") +
     xlab("instrument supersaturation(%)")})
```

Unfortunately, I been google searching and I can't find any methods to help with the problems I have encountered.

Comment: Generally if you want a model to use, you should fit the model directly and save the model object, not get `ggplot` to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason I used ggplot is because I previously used the logarithmic regression model to determine the equation for one of my plots and I was successful.  I then tried using the loop function, but couldn't figure it out. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The same suggestion above. `ggplot` is a plotting package. It's good at drawing plots, an in this case even putting nice lines on plots. But it's not a data modeling package. You want some data out of a model. Use `lm()` to fit your model. Save the model object. You can look at the `.fitted.values`, run predictions, view modesl statistics, etc. The suggestion is: if you want more out of a model than a plot, don't use `ggplot` to fit the model, only use it to plot the model.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help and being patient with me especially since I'm a beginner in using R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is not reproducible (since it relies on `rotated.plot.data` that is not available).

But from your question it seems all you want is to transform the X axis with the logarithm. There is a scale for that: `scale_x_log10()`. You can remove the `log()` from the `geom_smooth()` call add this scale to your plot.

Try this:

```
rotated.plot.data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=instrument.supersaturation, y={{ y }})) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") +
  scale_x_log10() +
  ylab("Nccn/Ncn") +
  xlab("instrument supersaturation(%)")
```